# Django - Protect media files with django-wiki

Tags: python, django, django-wiki

In the past I managed to protect my images in other projects in the following way:

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('media/<str:filename>/', views.media, name="media"),
]
```

`settings.py`

```
#MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

`views.py`

```
@login_required
def media(request, filename):
    import os
    from mimetypes import MimeTypes
    content_type, encoding = MimeTypes().guess_type(
        os.path.basename(filename)
    )
    if content_type is None or len(content_type) == 0:
        print(f'No content-type found for file: {filename}')
        content_type = 'text/plain'
    try:
        url = os.path.join(
            settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(filename)
        )
        with open(url.encode('utf-8'), 'rb') as f:
            resp = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type=content_type)
            # resp['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'
            resp['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex, nofollow'
            return resp
    except IOError as ex:
        data = {'ERROR': str(ex)}
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

With this, if someone tries to view for example an image via the url `www.example.com/media/image.png`, the user cannot see anything unless they are logged in.

I need to use the `django-wiki` system https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki  which I have installed in my existing project through `pip install wiki`.

Now my project works together with the wiki system.

Wiki system is installed in this path:

`/Users/{my_username}/.virtualenvs/{my_virtualenv_name}/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wiki/`

Is there any way to protect images in the same way for the wiki system?

I think modifying `.../site-packages/wiki/` views is not a good idea and perhaps there is a better solution to the problem posed.